# g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libstdc++’

Tags: makefile, g++

Hi I'm running a makefile that has the line

```
ADDLIBS = -stdlib=libstdc++ -L${BOOST_DIR}/lib -lboost_program_options
```

but I get the exception

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libstdc++’
```

Could someone tell me how I modify the makefile?

Answer (score 2):

That flag is for clang.  It's not a valid flag for GCC.  So just remove it:

```
ADDLIBS = -L${BOOST_DIR}/lib -lboost_program_options
```